# Typescript exporting namespace defined in multiple files

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am currently working on my first Typescript project. After going through the official documentation and watching some courses (egghead), I thought it was time to write real code - not just samples.

I am using:

- typescript@rc (~2.0.2)
- Visual Studio Code (~1.4.0)
- Windows 10

So I am working on a node module. My question here is about code structuring.

Here is how my project looks like:

```
 src/
|____ core/
|    |____ core.ts
|    |____ components.ts
|    |____ systems.ts
|____ input/
|    |____ input.system.ts
|    |____ keyboard.ts
|____ app.ts
```

Below is a sample of each files:

- core.ts

```js
/// <reference path="../core/components.ts" />

namespace Core {

    export interface IEntity {
        x: number
        y: number
        components: [Components.IComponent]
        update(dt: number): void
    }

    export class Entity implements IEntity {
        x: number
        y: number
        components: [Components.IComponent]
        update(dt: number): void{
            // do something with the coordinates
        }
    }
}
```

- components.ts

```js
namespace Components{
    export interface IComponent {
        update(dt: number): void
        // some other stuff here...
    }
}
```

- systems.ts

```js
namespace Systems{

    export interface ISystem{
        update(dt: number): void
        // some other stuff here...
    }

}
```

- input.system.ts

```js
/// <reference path="../core/systems.ts" />

namespace Systems{

    export class InputSystem implements ISystem{
        update(dt: number): void{
            // do something here
        }
        // some other stuff here...
    }

}
```

- keyboard.ts

```js
/// <reference path="../core/components.ts" />

namespace Components{
    export class Keyboard implements IComponent{
        update(dt: number): void{
            // do something here - Catch key up / down
        }
        // some other stuff here...
    }
}
```

- app.ts

```js
/// <reference path="./core/core.ts" />
/// <reference path="./core/components.ts" />
/// <reference path="./core/systems.ts" />

/// <reference path="./input/input.system.ts" />
/// <reference path="./input/keyboard.ts" />

export = {Core, Components, Systems}
```

What I want to do here is having 3 main namespaces Core, Components and Systems. Then if in another project this module is imported, we could do something like:

- other.module.ts

```js
// load module from node

import * as mymodule from "mymodule"

module A {
    class A extends mymodule.Core.Entity{
        constructor() {
            this.components.push(new mymodule.Components.Keyboard());
        }
    }

    export function main(): void{
       var systems: [mymodule.Systems.ISystem];

       systems.push(new mymodule.Systems.InputSystem());
       // other systems could be pushed Here

       for(var system in systems){
           system.update(0.5);
       }
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is in app.ts where for all namespaces compiler says:

```
cannot re export name that is not define
```

Is there something wrong with what I am doing?

I was also wondering if I should export using default in app.ts? like:

```
export default {Core, Components, Systems}
```

Would that help when importing my module?

Thanks,
Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my question was clear enough. I found a solution though, and would like your opinion.

So, I removed all the namespaces from my files. Which means that now all my files are modules.

Then at the root of my solution I create three files:

- _core.ts

```js
export * from "./core/core"
```

- _components.ts

```js
export * from "./core/components" 
export * from "./input/keyboard"
```

- _systems.ts

```js
export * from "./core/systems" 
export * from "./input/input.controller"
```

Now in my app.ts I can simply import those new files, like this.

```js
import * as Core from "./_core"
import * as Components from "./_components.ts"
import * as Systems from "._/systems.ts"

export = {Core, Components, Systems}
```

What do you think? Any potential issue by doing so?

Thanks,
Ed.